# Fill blanks with zeros on a newly created dynamic table

Tags: excel, vba

I am new using VBA. I just created a macro which I want the blanks to fill with zero automatically, in that same macro.
I have tried several ways but it marks me error.
Tried to use the following line of code:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TablaDepartamentos").NullString = "0"
```

I use this line of code since the pivot table is renamed:

```
'Rename pivot table 
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
    pt.Name = ws.Name

Next pt
Next ws
End With
```

Next, I leave the code for you to see what I am doing. Many thanks:

```
Sub PRUEBA()
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim PTCache As PivotCache

'Revisa que no existan hojas con ese nombre y si lo hay, lo alimina
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("TablaDepartamentos").Delete
On Error GoTo 0

'Obtener la informacion de la tabla
Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=Sheets("ECC-EWM").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address)


'Crear una nueva worksheet
Worksheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "TablaDepartamentos"

'Crear la tabla pivote
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add( _
    PivotCache:=PTCache, _
    TableDestination:=Range("A1"))

'Crear columna de la tabla
 With pt.PivotFields("System")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With

'Crear fila de la tabla
With pt.PivotFields("Depart")
 .Orientation = xlRowField
 .Position = 1
End With

'Table information
With pt.PivotFields("Count")
 .Orientation = xlDataField
 .Position = 1
 .Function = xlSum
 .NumberFormat = "#,##0"

'Rename pivot table 
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
    pt.Name = ws.Name

Next pt
Next ws
End With
End Sub
```

Thank you very much

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help without knowing the error messages you're getting.

I'm also quite new to VBA, but someone gave me this link about [qualifying references](https://www.spreadsheetsmadeeasy.com/7-common-vba-mistakes-to-avoid/), and it was very helpful in learning good coding practices.  From a first read through of your sub, I see you calling out a label, but then you don't have the label in there for it to goto.  The other thing I see right now that might be giving you trouble is the TableDestination:=Range("A1")).  You should call out the worksheet before the range function, so that it knows the full reference.